# How to change the Windows 7 Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: windows, keyboard

I've always been using the <kbd>CTRL + Alt + M</kbd> as the shortcuts in my Notepad++ to format the JSON strings, until now, when it is hijacked by a newly (forcefully) installed application (by my IT team, out of my control).

I.e., even when I have Notepad++ activated, pressing <kbd>CTRL + Alt + M</kbd> will no longer format the JSON strings any more, but pop up a weird dialog Windows (that I never seen before, would never use), which is really really annoying.

The closest hit I found for this problem is
[How do I change the Windows 7 Keyboard Shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-change-the-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts/0110d32d-66c0-4ce7-8682-eeb896e80c3f)

However, that one is for Windows key specifically, not for a none-default keys like this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows allows you to assign shortcut keys to .lnk files. I assume that <kbd>CTRL + Alt + M</kbd> has been assigned to some program. To change this, right click the offending file and open the properties dialogue and change the shortcut key property from <kbd>CTRL + Alt + M</kbd> to whatever you like.

You can do this in Powershell if you prefer.

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.shell
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("Path/to/offending/file.lnk")
$shortcut.hotkey = "" #remove shortcut keys
$shortcut.save()
```

Comment: Perfect! Took me quite a while to hunt down that offending .lnk file though.

Comment: I guess you could have written a script to find all .lnk files and check their hotkey property and removed them if it matchs CTRL + ALT + M, but hey it might have been faster to just check by hand if there weren't too many .Ink files